# How can I use NSNotFound in my NSString? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How can I make this code here:

```
- (NSString *) cheeseNameWithoutCheeseSuffix:(NSString *)cheeseName {
/* WORK HERE */
NSString *noCheese = cheeseName;
NSRange cheeseRange = [noCheese rangeOfString:@" cheese" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSString *withoutCheese = [noCheese stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:cheeseRange withString:@""];

return withoutCheese;
}
```

Work with this code with NSNotFound?

```
- (void)testThatRemovingCheeseSuffixWorksWithNoCheeseAtAll {
NSString *fullCheeseString = @"Gouda";
NSString *cheeseNameOnly = [self.stringCheese cheeseNameWithoutCheeseSuffix:fullCheeseString];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(cheeseNameOnly, @"Gouda", @"Gouda should be returned.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that *cheeseRange.location* is not equal to *NSNotFound*. But you can just try your code to see what it does!